# Is there a way to create custom XML tags in Microsoft SQL server and append nodes on the fly?

Tags: c#, sql, xml, xquery

I have a C# implementation of creating an XML for a large object (has multiple fields like message_description, message_time etc:

```
XmlNode rootElement = doc.CreateElement("message");
doc.AppendChild(rootElement);
AddTextNode(doc, rootElement, "ControlID", DateTime.Now.Ticks.ToString());
XmlNode MHI = doc.CreateElement("MessageHeaderInfo");
rootElement.AppendChild(MHI);
```

This will give me an XML like

```
<message>
  <ControlID>637310268897919044</ControlID>
  <MessageHeaderInfo>...
  </MessageHeaderInfo> 
</message>
```

The AddTextNode(..) method simply creates and adds a node to the given parent

```
void AddTextNode(XmlDocument doc, XmlNode parent, string newNodeName, string newNodeValue)
{
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(newNodeValue))
    {
        XmlNode newNode = doc.CreateElement(newNodeName);
        newNode.AppendChild(doc.CreateTextNode(newNodeValue));
        parent.AppendChild(newNode);
    }
}
```

I'm trying to implement this using a stored procedure, where multiple nodes can be created and the values of some will be the data from few tables in the database.
Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You could improve this question a bit by providing an example of what you wish to achieve as well as a sample of what you mean by `data from few tables`. Have you tried any methods of manipulating the XML in a stored procedure so far? If so, can you provide an example of what you have attempted?

Comment: What does this question have to do with SQL Server?

Comment: Look up `FOR XML` and XQuery.

Comment: How are you connecting to database (Entity or SQLClient)?

Comment: Divya, While asking a question, you need to provide a minimal reproducible example. Please refer to the following link:
https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example
Please provide the following:  
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT T-SQL statements. 
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it. 
(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in #1 above.
(4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;)

Comment: Divya, as many already pointed out, it is easily doable in SQL Server via **XQuery**. Please edit your original post, and provide all the details as I specified in my previous comment, i.e. ##1-4.